What exactly does the constants imply/mean in a regression analysis?
I have 2 regression equations $y=11.18e^{-0.972x}$ and $y=16.391e^{-2.246x}$.
From my understanding of regression, for $y=Ae^{Bx}$, $A$ is the constant that represents the initial amount changing/starting value before any decay occurs. Shouldn't the starting values be 577.33% and 234.67% ? How would 16.391 and 11.18 be the starting values? And how can I interpret these 2 values? Comparing the 2 equations, what would the difference between 16.391 and 11.18 indicate/imply?
As for the constant $B$, am I right in saying a higher $B$ means a faster rate of decay? So the decay constant of -2.246 would indicate a faster decay compared to -0.972?


If $x$ is the "Closing Price", then the "% Gain/Loss" should be $y = \frac{5.08-x}{x} = \frac{5.08}{x}-1$ (for one case). Then are you really trying to fit an exponential formula $y=Ae^{Bx}$?

$A=11.18$ and $A=16.391$ are the respective $y$ values obtained by setting $x=0$. Otherwise, what do you mean by "starting value"?

Thanks @peterwhy, it was fitted to $y=Ae^{Bx}$ as I was using exponential curve fitting in Excel, so I guess that's the default formula that excel uses.

One have to take care that the $y$ in the equation $y=Ae^{Bx}$  is not consistent with the $y$ in your data and on your graphs (because in % ). This can introduce an ambiguity on the numerical values of $A$ and $B$. In order to avoid ambiguity the symbols used below $(y,A,B)$ are those of the equation.
Answer to the first question : As for the constant $B$, am I right in saying an higher $B$ means a faster rate of decay? So the decay constant of -2.246 would indicate a faster decay compared to -0.972?
You are not right. That is the contrary:  A smaller $B$ means a faster rate of decay (i.e. A lower rate of increase).
You are right : The decay constant of -2.246 indicates a faster decay compared to -0.972
This is because -2.246 is smaller than -0.972.
This is visible on the next figure :

Answer of the second question : From my understanding of regression, for $y=Ae^{Bx}$, $A$ is the constant that represents the initial amount changing/starting value before any decay occurs. Shouldn't the starting values be 577.33% and 234.67% ? How would 16.391 and 11.18 be the starting values? And how can I interpret these 2 values? Comparing the 2 equations, what would the difference between 16.391 and 11.18 indicate/imply?
ANSWER :
$A$ is the decay value at $x=0$.
In your question it is not specified that the the measurements start at $x=0$.
In the first data set the first measurement $y=2.3467$ is at $x=0.75\:$  This must not be confused with $y=16.391$ at $x=0$.
In the second data set the first measurement $y=5.7733$ is at $x=0.75\:$  This must not be confused with $y=11.18$ at $x=0$.
Nothing in the wording of the question specifies that the "amount changing/starting value before any decay occurs" is at the first measurement $x=0.75$. On the other hand the equation model $y=Ae^{Bx}$ draw to think that the "amount changing/starting value before any decay occurs" might be at $x=0$. This can be interpreted as an ambiguous modelisation.

Thanks so much @JJacquelin, you've explained it very clearly and it's as perfect of an answer as I could get. Understood the points you've made, especially on the y in the data vs on the graphs (% vs numerical). Thanks again, most appreciated!
